# HANA list / show tables SQL Command

Tags: sql, hana

How to show / list all tables in SAP HANA via SQL?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

SAP HANA provides a database catalog (just like most other DBMS) via system tables like [TABLES](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/21/0197377519101481cfb213f0b84848/content.htm), VIEWS, USERS, etc. ...
These are the ANSI-92 compliant metadata views.

Instead of the *INFORMATION_SCHEMA* SAP HANA provides these views in the *PUBLIC* schema (again, like other DBMS do that).

Example:

```
select * from tables
select * from public.tables
```

The M_TABLES provides information about the runtime objects that represent tables.

Comment: Downvote because of what? The answer I provided is accurate and complete.

Comment: TABLES and the other metadata views are VIEWS in schema SYS, and at the same time PUBLIC SYNONYMS (in schema PUBLIC). But this should be no reason at all for a downvote! Whoever downvoted should at least provide a better answer or comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM SYS.M_TABLES
```

Comment: `M_TABLES` is a system view that provides **runtime information** on tables - it's not the primary catalog view to query for tables. For example, it does not include *virtual tables*, where `TABLES` does.

Answer (score 0):

To view tables from a specific schema :

```
select * from SYS.M_TABLES where SCHEMA_NAME ='<your schema name goes here>'
```

Comment: same problem with `M_TABLES` as explained in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This below query will list all your schema tables

select * from tables where SCHEMA_NAME ='schema_name'

Answer (score -3):

It is my understanding that HANA is compatible with ANSI SQL.  If this is actually the case, the following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Of course, I don't have access to a hana instance to prove this.

**CORRECTION**:
After looking at some documentation, it looks like SAP supports this type of thing through a SYS schema:

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/cbb10c75191014b47ba845bfe499fe/content.htm?frameset=/en/2e/1ef8

So, I think you would actually select from:

```
SYS.M_TABLES
```

Comment: M_TABLES is not providing information on all tables in the database, but runtime information on ROW- and COLUMNstore information.